# Call webservice function from Windows phone

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone

I have created a webservice and a method as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool GetMasterExit(int RoomID)
{
    if(GameList[RoomID][0] == "\0")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

And then I call this from WP client using the following way but there is a problem that I want the main process blocked until the webservice returns the value I want but in this way the value is wrong for delay.

I have tried to use the Await but I got an error that "cannot await void", so Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

```
public void Test()
{
    ServiceSoapClient GameClient = new ServiceSoapClient();
    GameClient.GetMasterExitCompleted += _clientGetMasterExitCompleted;
    GameClient.GetMasterExitAsync(RoomID);
    Console.WriteLine(MasterExit);
}


public void _clientGetMasterExitCompleted(object sender, GetMasterExitCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MasterExit = e.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use `await` then you must add modifier `async` to your function signature.Hope this helps.

Use `async` and `await` like this:

```
public async void Test() 
{
    ServiceSoapClient GameClient = new ServiceSoapClient();
    GameClient.GetMasterExitCompleted += _clientGetMasterExitCompleted;
    await GameClient.GetMasterExitAsync(RoomID);
    Console.WriteLine(MasterExit);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code like this:

1. On Web Service:
[WebMethod]
public Task<bool> GetMasterExit(int RoomID)
{
    if(GameList[RoomID][0] == "\0")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


2. On Windows Phone APP:

public async void Test()
{
    ServiceSoapClient GameClient = new ServiceSoapClient();
    MasterExit = await GameClient.GetMasterExitAsync(RoomID);
    Console.WriteLine(MasterExit);
}

Unfortunately, the re is a error in "MasterExit = await GameClient.GetMasterExitAsync(RoomID);" ,
saying that "cannot await void". I totally lose it. :(

Comment: public async<Task> Test() { ServiceSoapClient GameClient = new ServiceSoapClient(); MasterExit = await GameClient.GetMasterExitAsync(RoomID); Console.WriteLine(MasterExit); }

Try this as you can not use async with void when you have called await in that function.

Comment: No, It doesn't help and I wonder if you can help me modify these two methods?

Comment: Hi, vits, In "await GameClient.GetMasterExitAsync(RoomID)" this line, there is an error says that "cannot await void "

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803370/using-async-await-inside-void-method) and get understanding of how to use await.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> I want the main process blocked until the webservice returns the value

This is an incorrect approach. Especially on mobile platforms such as WP, you're not allowed to block the UI like that.

The proper solution is to use `await`. Follow the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and write an [EAP wrapper called `GetMasterExitTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP).

Comment: hey I still don't know how to resolve this problem with EAP and TAP. Could you please help me modify this two methods?

Comment: The second link in my answer has an example that shows how to wrap EAP with TAP.